# Insert data into custom object with php salesforce toolkit

Tags: custom-object, php

I can insert data to salesforce in any standard object  Like Leads, Contacts etc . But my client has created a custom object .  That object name is survey , and there are several survey questions Like  your occupation ? Do you own or rent etc . I can't insert data into Survey .   In case of Standard object I can insert data by using salesforce php toolkit  . Like below

```
 $lead = new stdClass;
 $lead->type = '';
 $lead->fields = array(
      'Own_Or_Rent__c' => 'Own',
      'Your_Occupation__c' =>'Job',

 );
$result = $mySforceConnection_enterprise->create(array($lead), 'Lead');
```

But in this case my client has provided me with the ID of the the object "Survey__c" and and ids of those question like a04g000000CcfSAAAZ, a04g000000CcfSPAAZ etc . How can I insert survey result with these kind of info ?

I have tried like this

```
 $lead = new stdClass;
 $lead->type = '';
 $lead->fields = array(
      a04g000000CcfSAAAZ => 'Own',
      'Your_Occupation__c' => 'Job',

 );
$result = $mySforceConnection_enterprise->create(array($lead), 'Survey__c');
```

But it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the information you got it might be a little hard to understand what the architecture is.

I have a feeling that there are 2 object, one is the Survey__c object and the other is the one whose ids he provided. Ids in salesforce are given to existing records, so there is no way to insert a record and specify an id. You can use the id to update records though.

Think of a salesforce id like a SQL GUID. Each record in a table will have a different system given id.

Your customer will have to specify what type of records contain those ids and then you can go from there.

Hope this helps you!